# How to repeat part of this JS function forever every 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

Okay, so heres the full source of my function. All I want that the part that is surrounded by "////////////" would repeat. New function works too. I could have them both, very confused once I tried to pull the highlighted function into a new one and got loads of errors.

```
function reWebLogOn(steam, callback) {
    steam.webLogOn(function(newCookie){
        helper.msg('webLogOn ok');
        cookies = newCookie;
        offers.setup({
            sessionID: currentSessionId,
            webCookie: newCookie
        }, function(){
            if (typeof callback == "function") {
                callback();
            }
        }); 
        var steamcommunityMobileConfirmations = new SteamcommunityMobileConfirmations(
    {
      steamid:         config.steamid,
      identity_secret: config.identitySecret,
      device_id:       device_id,
      webCookie:       newCookie,
    });


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.FetchConfirmations((function (err, confirmations)
{
    if (err)
    {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.FetchConfirmations received ' + confirmations.length + ' confirmations');
    if ( ! confirmations.length)
    {
        return;
    }
    steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.AcceptConfirmation(confirmations[0], (function (err, result)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.AcceptConfirmation result: ' + result);
    }).bind(this));
}).bind(this));

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    });  
}
```

Comment: is `FetchConfirmations` what you want looped or the content inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use timer's, an Interval would be handy

```
setInterval(function() {
    //.. part that should be repleated
}, 30*1000);
```

Comment: Best answer is right here, folks ^ not sure why others are giving unnecessarily complicated demos beyond the scope of the question. Answers should be minimally viable with an optional *additional* advanced example.

Comment: @dylanh724 dear "throne of lie founder" glad to see you here.

Answer (score 0):

`window.setInterval()` is your friend.
it executes a function at the provided interval of time.
for example, `setInterval(()=>console.log("foo"),100)` will log "foo" in the console every 100ms.

```
function reWebLogOn(steam, callback) {
    steam.webLogOn(function(newCookie){
        helper.msg('webLogOn ok');
        cookies = newCookie;
        offers.setup({
            sessionID: currentSessionId,
            webCookie: newCookie
        }, function(){
            if (typeof callback == "function") {
                callback();
            }
        }); 
        var steamcommunityMobileConfirmations = new SteamcommunityMobileConfirmations(
    {
      steamid:         config.steamid,
      identity_secret: config.identitySecret,
      device_id:       device_id,
      webCookie:       newCookie,
    });


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

setInterval((function(){
  steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.FetchConfirmations((function (err, confirmations){
    if (err)
    {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.FetchConfirmations received ' + confirmations.length + ' confirmations');
    if ( ! confirmations.length)
    {
        return;
    }
    steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.AcceptConfirmation(confirmations[0], (function (err, result)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('steamcommunityMobileConfirmations.AcceptConfirmation result: ' + result);
    }).bind(this));
  }).bind(this));
}).bind(this),30000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside setInterval(function(){},1000) timer or do some recursive calls.